# Is it possible to access row index inside DataFramesMeta macros?

Tags: julia, dataframesmeta.jl

Is there a way to access **current_row_index** in the following snippet ?

```
@with df begin
    fn.(:col, current_row_index)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, since you are broacasting just pass first axes of `df`:

```
julia> using DataFramesMeta

julia> fn(x, y) = (x, y)
fn (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df = DataFrame(col=["a", "b", "c"])
3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ col
     │ String
─────┼────────
   1 │ a
   2 │ b
   3 │ c

julia> @with df begin
           fn.(:col, axes(df, 1))
       end
3-element Vector{Tuple{String, Int64}}:
 ("a", 1)
 ("b", 2)
 ("c", 3)
```